# Unable to Install dm-sqlite-adapter Gem on Windows PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to Ruby/Sinatra and I am trying to install the DataMapper SQLite Adapter. When I run `gem install dm-sqlite-adapter` I get the message below.  I did previously install sqlite3 using the command `gem install sqlite3`.  However, if I try to call `gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby`, I get errors.

> ```
>   c:\Ruby_Dev_Kit>gem install dm-sqlite-adapter
> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing dm-sqlite-adapter:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>     C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> checking for sqlite3.h... no
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
> libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
> need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>         --with-opt-dir
>         --without-opt-dir
>         --with-opt-include
>         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>         --with-opt-lib
>         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>         --with-make-prog
>         --without-make-prog
>         --srcdir=.
>         --curdir
>         --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
>         --with-sqlite3-dir
>         --without-sqlite3-dir
>         --with-sqlite3-include
>         --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>         --with-sqlite3-lib
>         --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
>
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/do_sq
> lite3-0.10.13 for inspection.
> Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.13/ext
> /do_sqlite3/gem_make.out
> ```

I have tried multiple different approaches to get around this issue. I was able to install the Ruby Development Kit as I was able to install the JSON gem.  Similarly I downloaded the SQLite source code from [SQLite.org](http://sqlite.org/) but I was not able to figure out how to properly configure all aspects of the amalgamation to be found by the tool.  Below is the `mkmf.log`'s value:

```
have_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wall  -DHAVE_NO_DATETIME_NEWBANG conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -L/usr/local/ -L/opt/local/ -L/usr/ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wall  -DHAVE_NO_DATETIME_NEWBANG  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

I tried many different things to get it working, and I realize this may be a stupid question. However, at this point, I am out of ideas.  Any assistance would be really appreciated.

**System Information:**

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Ruby Version: 2.0.0 p247 x64
- Installer - Standard Ruby Exe Installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually was able to work around this issue.  For those who run into this on the future, Bosko Ivanisevic wrote a great guide how to work around this.

See here: http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-05.html

Many details in there to be careful about so be sure to read through it step by step and follow everything exactly.  Great explanation.